# Intersection of convex hulls

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls, decision-problems

I have two polyhedral sets $\mathscr{P}_1, \mathscr{P}_2,$ defined as convex hulls

$$\mathscr{P}_1 = \mbox{conv} \left\{ v_{1},\dots, v_{N} \right\}, \qquad \mathscr{P}_2 = \mbox{conv} \left\{ w_{1},\dots,w_{M} \right\}$$

If $\mathscr{P}_1 \bigcap \mathscr{P}_2 \neq \emptyset$, then there is a point that is in convex hull $v_{1},\dots, v_{N}$ and in convex hull $w_{1},\dots, w_{N}$. I have to find this point by using linear programming. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Start from the definition of a point in the convex hull of $\mathscr P_1$, and the same for $\mathscr P_2$.

Comment: Alright, I think i have an idea, and what should be my minimization funciton? I mean what functioin should I minimize (min f(x))

Comment: This is a feasibility problem, not an optimization problem. You can minimize any dummy function you want - with the simplex method, you'll have to use some kind of two-stage method, and the first stage would be the part that actually solves the problem.

Comment: If you think you've got it, I recommend you write an answer here when you're done - it will help other people later, and you can get feedback. Or if you still have questions, add your attempt to the question and I will help you finish the problem.

Comment: A hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two sets intersect, then there must be a point $\vec p \in \mathscr{P}_1 \cap \mathscr{P}_2$, representable as a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of both the set of points $\{\vec v_1,\ldots,\vec v_N \}$ and the set of points $\{\vec w_1,\ldots,\vec v_M\}$. Let's denote a vector of coefficients, participating in these combinations, as:

$$\vec \alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N,\alpha_{N+1},\ldots,\alpha_{N+M}) \in \mathbb R^{N+M}$$

We can express the point $\vec p$ as either of two vector sums below:

$$\vec p = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \vec v_i = \sum_{j=N+1}^{N+M} \alpha_j \vec w_j $$

The components of the vector $\vec \alpha$ must also satisfy two scalar equations:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i = 1,\sum_{j=N+1}^{N+M} \alpha_j = 1$$

We can represent three equations above in the matrix form:

$$A\vec\alpha = b$$

where the matrix $A$ contains $(d+2)$ rows and $(N+M)$ columns, and the vector $b$ contains $(d+2)$ elements ($d$ - the number of dimensions of the vector space, containing points $v_i$ and $w_j$):

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec v_1 \cdots \vec v_N & -\vec w_1 \cdots -\vec w_M \\
1 \cdots 1 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0 \cdots 0 & 1 \cdots 1 
\end{bmatrix},
b =
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec 0 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If this system of linear equations above has a solution $\vec \alpha \ge 0$ (the non-negativity is necessary for the convex combination), then two sets $\mathscr{P}_1$ and $\mathscr{P}_2$ have a non-empty intersection.

It's convenient to use the [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) to determine the solvability of the system above. According to this lemma, the existence of the vector $\vec\beta$, such that inequalities below are satisfied:

$$
b^T\vec\beta < 0 \\
A^T\vec\beta \ge 0
$$

guarantees, that the matrix equation $A\vec\alpha = b$ **doesn't** have a solution $\vec\alpha \ge 0$. Also, the matrix inequality $A^T\vec\beta \ge 0$ always has a solution $\vec\beta=0$.  So, we just need to start from this initial solution and try to minimize the value of the scalar product $b^T\vec\beta$. As soon as we find a vector $\vec\beta$, such that this scalar product is negative, we can conclude, that the original matrix equation is not solvable (no intersection). If we get stuck on the solution $\vec\beta=0$, then the matrix equation is solvable (the intersection is not empty).

---

**EXAMPLE**. Let's consider two segments on the plane, i.e. $d=n=M=2$.

$$
\vec v_1=(v_{1x},v_{1y}),\vec v_2=(v_{2x},v_{2y}),
\vec w_1=(w_{1x},w_{1y}),\vec w_2=(w_{2x},w_{2y})
$$

The (dual) Linear Programming problem will become:

$$b^T\vec\beta = \beta_3 + \beta_4 \to min$$

subject to constraints $A^T\vec\beta \ge 0$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 v_{1x} &  v_{1y} & 1 & 0 \\
 v_{2x} &  v_{2y} & 1 & 0 \\
-w_{1x} & -w_{1y} & 0 & 1 \\
-w_{2x} & -w_{2y} & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\beta_3 \\
\beta_4 
\end{bmatrix}
\ge
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**The case, when two segments intersect:**

$$\vec v_1=(1,1),\vec v_2=(2,2),\vec w_1=(2,1),\vec w_2=(1,2)$$

We get a system of inequalities:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  \beta_1 +  \beta_2 + \beta_3 \ge 0 \\
 2\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 + \beta_3 \ge 0 \\
-2\beta_1 -  \beta_2 + \beta_4 \ge 0 \\
 -\beta_1 - 2\beta_2 + \beta_4 \ge 0
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$

Let's add these four inequalities:

$$2(\beta_3 + \beta_4) \ge 0$$

Therefore, the objective function can't be negative, and we conclude, that two segments $conv\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2\}$ and $conv\{\vec w_1,\vec w_2\}$ do intersect (which is obvious, if you draw them).

**The case, when two segments don't intersect:**

$$\vec v_1=(2,2),\vec v_2=(3,3),\vec w_1=(2,1),\vec w_2=(1,2)$$

We get a system of inequalities:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 2\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 + \beta_3 \ge 0 \\
 3\beta_1 + 3\beta_2 + \beta_3 \ge 0 \\
-2\beta_1 -  \beta_2 + \beta_4 \ge 0 \\
 -\beta_1 - 2\beta_2 + \beta_4 \ge 0
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$

It's easy to see that the vector $\vec\beta = (1,1,-4,3)$ is a solution of the system above, and the objective function value is negative on this vector (actually this value can be made a negative infinity). Therefore we can conclude, that two segments $conv\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2\}$ and $conv\{\vec w_1,\vec w_2\}$ don't intersect (again, it's obvious if to draw them).

Comment: Wow, really nice solution, how could I find separating hyperplane of these two (not intersecting) convex hulls?

Comment: @Anonymous - you need to find a pair of points $p_1 \in \mathscr P_1$ and $p_2 \in \mathscr P_2$ with minimum distance between them, and then to construct a hyperplane, orthogonally  halving the segment $(p_1,p_2)$. Please see: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224108603_A_Fast_Geometric_Algorithm_for_Finding_the_Minimum_Distance_Between_Two_Convex_Hulls

Comment: Hi @HEKTO , this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4441875/585488

Comment: @LiNKeR - you've got a good answer. Your "formula" is existence of this λ vector - if it exists then the point is inside the polytope, and vice versa.

Comment: @HEKTO much thanks

Comment: Hi @HEKTO this may be too much to ask but please could you take a look at the answer and help with what $\lambda$ represents. I made a comment on the answer.  I still don’t get how I am supposed to compute it